# Find the volume of resulting solid using any method: $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$; about y-axis;

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

In my textbook, I had a question:

**The region bounded by the $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ is rotated about the y-axis. Find the volume of resulting solid using any method.**

I did using shell method:

Radius: $-y$.

Circumference: $-2\pi y$.

Height: $x=\sqrt{1-(y-1)^2}$.

So, The Volume is:

$$V=-2\pi \int_{-1}^1y\sqrt{1-(y-1)^2}$$ or $$-2\pi \int_{-1}^1y\sqrt{y(2-y)}$$
So, I stuck here. Using substitution ($z=y(2-y)$) did not make any sense to calculate this integral. What can I do next or are there any alternative methods to solve this problem?

Comment: $-1\leq y\leq1$ or $0\leq y\leq2$ ?

Comment: I think  $0≤y≤2$, P.S. I am a beginner in this sphere...

Comment: Use $\pi\int x^2 dy$ and find the answer!

Comment: Thanks @MyGlasses...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are rotating about the $y$ axis, then you need only the right half of the circle and you know it will be a sphere with volume $\frac{4\pi}{3}$. By the shell method

$$ 2\pi rh=4\pi x\sqrt{1-x_2} $$

$$ \int_0^12\pi rh\,dx=2\pi\int_0^12x(\sqrt{1-x^2})\,dx =\left[-\frac{4\pi}{3}(1-x^2)^{3/2}\right]_0^1=\frac{4\pi}{3}$$

Comment: I suppose, I messed up x-axis and y-axis...

Comment: If you want to rotate about the $x$-axis it will be a torus.